# place mark on a specified point along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, pgf-decorations

I would like to place a mark on a highly complex path:

[image]

The mark should be at exactly 0.1 from beginning:

I try:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
\coordinate (C) at (2, -1);
\coordinate (D) at (3, 0.5);

\draw plot [smooth] coordinates { (A) (B) (C) (D) };
\path [
   postaction={decorate},
     decoration={
       markings,
       mark = at position {0.1\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax} with {fill = red circle (0.5cm)}
  }
] plot [smooth] coordinates { (A) (B) (C) (D) };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get an error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just say `0.1`, this is understood as 10% of the decorated path length. Also, `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` is not a length, just a macro. And you need to add normal Ti*k*Z commands like `\draw`, not just pgf keys.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
\coordinate (C) at (2, -1);
\coordinate (D) at (3, 0.5);

\draw plot [smooth] coordinates { (A) (B) (C) (D) };
\path [
   postaction={decorate},
     decoration={
       markings,
       mark = at position 0.1 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=0.5cm];}
  }
] plot [smooth] coordinates { (A) (B) (C) (D) };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]