# tikz: place a mark on a straight line

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-decorations

[place mark on a specified point along path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497362/place-mark-on-a-specified-point-along-path) discusses placing a mark on a complicated path, but placing a mark on a simple straight line is nevertheless difficult.

I try:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \path [
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark = at position {0.1\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax} with {fill = red circle (0.5cm)}
    }
  ] (A) -- (B) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the output

[image]

the mark is nowhere to be seen.

What is wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same result you can obtain without `decorations.markings`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
\draw  (A) -- (B) node[pos=0.1, circle,fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure where you got that syntax for the mark from, you need

```
mark = at position 0.1 with {\fill [red] circle (0.5cm);}
```

As Schrödinger's cat mentioned in a comment, you don't need any `\pgfdecorationpathlength` at all, a number is interpreted as a fractional distance along the path. (If you do want to use `\pgfdirectionpathlength`, just `0.1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength` is enough, no `\dimexpr` needed.) And the actual mark needs to be a proper path.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \path [
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark = at position 0.1 with {\fill [red] circle [radius=0.1cm];}
    }
  ] (A) -- (B) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, I'd entirely forgotten that. Will edit my answer.