# Find midpoint of path

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-graphs, tikz-path

I have two coordinates (v1) and (v2) which are connected by a bended path. Now I would like to connect a third variable (v3) to the middle point of this path, but I cannot figure out how.

```
\coordinate (v1) at (-2,0);
\coordinate (v2) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (v3) at (-1,0);

\draw[fill, black] (v1) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[fill, black] (v2) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[fill, black] (v3) circle[radius=1pt];

\path [bend left] (v1) edge (v2);
```

No I want to connect (v3) to the middle point of the path from (v1) to (v2). I trid using decorations like here [place mark on a specified point along path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497362/place-mark-on-a-specified-point-along-path) with

```
\path [bend left,
   postaction={decorate},
     decoration={
       markings,
       mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}
  }
] (v1) edge (v2);
```

but this always collects (v1). Furthermore, I do not know how to adress this mark.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For TikZ, the midpoint `M` of a path can be get when going along the path and pick a coordinate at the position `pos=.5`

```
\draw (v1) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=.5] (M) (v2);
```

[image]

TikZ code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
\draw[lightgray] (-3,-1) grid (1,2);
\path 
(-2,0) coordinate (v1)      
(-1,1) coordinate (v2)
(0,0)  coordinate (v3)
;
\draw (v1) to[bend left=50] coordinate[pos=.5] (M) (v2);
\draw[red] (M)--(v3);

\path 
(v1)  node[left,fill=white]{$v_1$}  node[dot]{} 
(v2)  node[right,fill=white]{$v_2$} node[dot]{}
(v3)  node[right,fill=white]{$v_3$} node[dot]{}
(M)   node[above left,fill=white]{$M$} node[dot,red]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

For Asymptote, the midpoint `M` of a path `p` can be get via

```
pair M=relpoint(p,.5);
```

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1.5cm);
import math;   // for grid
add(shift(-3,-1)*grid(4,3,lightgray));
pair v1=(-2,0), v2=(-1,1), v3=(0,0);

path p=v1 {dir(80)} ..  v2 {dir(-20)};
pair M=relpoint(p,.5);    // the midpoint of the path p
draw(p,blue);
draw(M--v3,red);

dot("$v_1$",align=W,v1);
dot("$v_2$",align=E,v2);
dot("$v_3$",align=E,v3);
dot(M,red);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! That looks great!

Comment: @samabu For TikZ, `bend left` makes the curve evenly bending, see my update. For Asymptote, I have not found its equivalence (I believe there is). Let me check more.